# Unexplainable WPF bug binding to static field

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got a class in a central library that has a slider that we use to control zoom.  We've got a static field that sets a system wide maximum zoom level we support.  It's kind of important since we use that value to coerce the range from multiple zoom paths, and we have to support legacy WinForms apps with the same concept.

```
public class ZoomableClass
{
    // really integers, but has to be a double to support binding to
    // WPF Slider.Maximum
    public const double MaxZoomLevel = 19;
}
```

In the XAML I naively thought I should be able to do the following:

```
<Slider Maximum="{x:Static core:ZoomableClass.MaxZoomLevel}" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type core:ZoomView}}, Path=ViewModel.(core:ZoomViewModel.ZoomLevel)}"/>
```

Aside from the editor complaining, when I ran the app the Debug log was stuck in a loop recording binding failures on the `Slider.Value` property.  When I changed the `{x:Static}` value back to a constant, everything ran just fine again.

To work around the issue and still use the constant, I declared it in the control resources:

```
<mvvm:View.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <x:Static Member=core:ZoomableClass.MaxZoomLevel" x:Key="MaxZoomLevel"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</mvvm:View.Resources>
```

Later I bound the slider property to the static resource:

```
<Slider Maximum="{StaticResource MaxZoomLevel}" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type core:ZoomView}}, Path=ViewModel.(core:ZoomViewModel.ZoomLevel)}""/>
```

This works at run time, but the designer is complaining telling me `An object of the type "System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Double".`

Hopefully the designer issue is fixed in more current versions (we are on Visual Studio 2010), but when I open that file in the designer the whole Slider has that ugly red 'x' for a broken control.  I open a XAML file that uses that control, and it renders just fine.

Can someone explain to me why my first attempt did not work, and is there a way to do this without the designer complaining to me?

Comment: Works for me: http://pastebin.com/KcakV19w

Comment: I think the combination of binding items caused the problems.  We have a non-trivial binding expression for the Value of the zoom slider.